# latexdiff for IEEE trans using texstudio

Tags: latexdiff

Trying to use latexdiff for an IEEE paper, I got lots of errors for compiling it using Pdflatex. Any idea why? what is the best configuration of latexdiff. Note that the original documents was compiled and build safely, but when comparing them I got lots of errors. Most of them indicating missing `{` or `}` in equation environments.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.